# Create a Theme with Material-ui and ClojureScript

Tags: material-ui, clojurescript

I have imported the material-ui `createMuiTheme` like so:

```
(:require ["@material-ui/core" :as ui]
["@material-ui/core/styles" :refer [createMuiTheme]])
```

Than I def the following :

```
(def theme (createMuiTheme #js {:palette #js {:primary {:main "red"}}}))
```

But I get the error saying bellow:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createMuiTheme' of undefined

How do I call into Material-ui to get the Theme?

Answer (score 0):

you might miss the MuiThemeProvider

```
["@material-ui/core" :as mui]
["@material-ui/core/styles" :refer [createMuiTheme]]


(def base-theme (createMuiTheme (clj->js {:palette #js {:primary {:main "red"}}})))

(defn Desktop []
  [:div
   [:> mui/MuiThemeProvider
    {:theme base-theme}
    [:div ....]])
```